# Why does my sagemaker model need a larger instance for real-time inference

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, amazon-sagemaker

I have a sagemaker endpoint that serves a Random Forest Classifier SKLearn model. This model predicts the kind of user someone is based on there interaction on a website. **I have had two releases for this model**.

The first model had 4 kinds of user: `'user-type-1', 'user-type-2', 'user-type-3', 'other'`

The second release differed from the first in that there was more training data used and there were 10 types of user `'user-type-1', 'user-type-2', 'user-type-3', 'user-type-4', 'user-type-5', 'user-type-6', 'user-type-7', 'user-type-8', 'user-type-9','other'`. To be more specific, in the first model many users got predicted as `'other'` whereas in the second model many of these users were in one of the new categories.

**The parameters for the random forest was the same in both models**.

**Question:** The second model uses a lot more memory than the first and I cannot figure out why. Both models are of similar size and the same number of calls to the endpoint are being made under the second release. Any ideas why I might need a larger instance with more memory in the second model than the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values` attribute of classification-type SkLearn tree models is essentially a data matrix `(n_leaves, n_classes)` (probability distributions associated with each leaf node).

In the first experiment this matrix has 4 columns, in the second experiment it has 10 columns - a 2.5X increase in size.

Comment: So each leaf will store the probability of each class should you request that back from the model. And that data is 2.5x as big?

Comment: The size of the `values` attribute is 2.5X as big. Other tree attributes are the same.

Comment: The predicted probability distribution (`predict_proba`) is the average of all leaf probability distributions. So, by definition, each leaf node must hold a `(n_classes)` double array. It's in the Scikit-Learn source code. Read for yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!